# How does an interpreter resolve function calls or branch(jump) statement?

Tags: interpreter

I know the question seems a bit broad. I tried searching for answers, couldn't find much.If anyone could describe or point me to the right source.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a bytecode-based interpreter, the usual way to do this would be as follows:

You have a variable, the program counter, which tells you the index of the instruction to execute. Usually you increase that counter by 1, but when executing a branch, you instead set it to the target location of the jump.

For function calls you do the same thing, but you also push the old value of the counter plus one onto the call stack. Then when you execute the return instruction, you pop the value of the stack and set the counter to that.

Comment: (Not the op.) So with a function, you're keeping the last location of execution before the function was initiated, and putting that next (so it knows where to return after the function completes and returns control)?

Comment: How will the branch target or address of the first instruction of the function be known?

Comment: @mohammedsiddiq Those would be part of the instruction. Like if you read the instruction `jmp 42`, you know that the target address is 42. The important part would be to generate correct indices in the first place. A common way to do that is to first generate bytecode with symbolic labels and then replace them in an extra step where you associate each label with its address.